# What am I doing wrong. I want to print to the fv value when I invoke the function

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong. I want to print to the fv value when I invoke the function.

```py
def future_value(P,i,n,t): #create function that takes of P,i,n,t.
    fv=P*(1+i/n)**(n*t) #equation for the amount of money in the account after the specified number of years.
    return(fv) #returns fv after function is complete. 


future_value(10000,.14,12,10) #prints P = 10,000, i = 14%, n = 12 (interest compounded monthly), t = 10 years
print(format(fv, ".2f")) #print float to 2 decimal places

future_value(12000,.12,4,50) #prints P = 12,000, i = 12%, n = 4 (interest compounded quarterly), t = 50 years
print(format(fv, ".2f")) #print float to 2 decimal places

future_value(100000,.23,1,20) #prints P = 100,000, i = 23%, n = 1 (interest compounded yearly), t = 20 years
print(format(fv, ".2f")) #print float to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: You need to assign the return value

Comment: Please add an example of expected output.

Comment: Add an expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) pointed out, you need to assign the return value of `future_value()` to a variable:

```
fv = future_value(10000,.14,12,10)
print(format(fv, ".2f"))
```

**But there is already a variable `fv` inside the function?**

Yes, but that variable isn't visible outside the function (local variable):

```
def future_value(P,i,n,t):
    fv=P*(1+i/n)**(n*t)  # Define local variable "fv"

# There is no variable called "fv" here
```